# Is it implied that Stuart is homosexual?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dig

In the 2021 film *The Dig*, two of the archaeologists are married -- Peggy and Stuart. The movie makes clear that they are having marital problems. I've just finished watching the film, and am confused whether it is trying to imply that Stuart is homosexual.

In the film, we see:

- Peggy 'forgets' to lock the door while she is taking a bath (unsure if intentional or accidental); when she returns to their room, Stuart scolds her and rebuffs her advances and awkwardly flees the room to take his own bath.
- Stuart clearly prefers the company of the other archaeologists -- specifically one whose name I'm not sure is ever mentioned (or is mentioned briefly as a minor character).

  - When Stuart goes to take some iron pieces to the lab for analysis, he is accompanying this other archaeologist; there is a brief discussion with Peggy where it seems as though she is implying that he prefers the other's company to hers.
- At the very end, during the pub scene while Chamberlain's (?) announcement of war is being broadcast, Stuart leaves the others and follows another person to a back room. It's very dimly lit but it might be the other male archeologist from the previous points.

I've read up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dig_(2021_film)) the background of this movie, as it was based on historical events. [Peggy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Guido) and [Stuart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuart_Piggott) are real individuals, each with their respective Wikipedia articles, neither of which indicates anything of the sort -- though they did divorce in 1956 (approximately 17 years after the events in the film.) The article about the film says that Peggy is "badly neglected" by Stuart, but nothing else.

So, is the movie trying to imply that Peggy and Stuart's marital problems are due to Stuart's homosexuality? <sub>Or did I and the five other people watching this film with me somehow all manage to come to this conclusion independently and erroneously...?</sub>